# Hard inequality with conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $g_i+b_i$ is odd for all $i$, and $b_1>g_1$, prove that :

$G(\frac{b_1}{g_1}+\frac{b_2}{g_2}+\frac{b_3}{g_3}+\frac{B}{G})$ > $B(\frac{g_1}{b_1}+\frac{g_2}{b_2}+\frac{g_3}{b_3}+\frac{G}{B})$,

where $B=b_1b_2b_3$ and $G=g_1g_2g_3$.

I don't know where to start

Answer (score 0):

I assume all $g_i$s and $b_i$s are positive, and $b_i>g_i$ for $i=1,2,3$.

Let $r_i=\frac{b_i}{g_i}$ for $i=1,2,3$. Then the above inequality is equivalent to:
\begin{align*}
r_1+r_2+r_3+r_1r_2r_3&> r_1r_2r_3\left(\frac1{r_1}+\frac1{r_2}+\frac1{r_3}\right)+1\\
\Leftrightarrow (r_1-1)(r_2-1)(r_3-1)&>0
\end{align*}

If $b_i>g_i$ for $i=1,2,3$, then you get $r_i>1$, and the above inequality follows.

Comment: Then you can construct a counterexample easily, following the above argument. (such as in the case $b_2/g_2=r_2>1$ and $b_3/g_3=r_3<1$)